# What do I do wrong with delete keyword in class destructor?

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator

I have next class:

```
class IntArray
{
public:
    explicit IntArray(size_t a = 0) {
        this->poi = new int[a];
        this->siz = a;
    };
    ~IntArray() {
         delete[] this->poi;
     };
private:
    size_t siz;
    int* poi;
};
```

In main something like next code:

```
IntArray iaa(5);
iaa.~IntArray();
```

But compiler says that there is a heap corruption in destructor. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Aren't you calling it twice?

Comment: if you have a question about a compiler error please include the compiler error in the question, though heap corruption rather sounds like a runtime error, also in this case please include the full error message in the question

Comment: *"What do I do wrong?"* -- calling the destructor explicitly. It will be called automatically when `iaa` goes out of scope. So now it's being called twice.

Comment: `iaa.~IntArray();` calling the destructor explicitly is almost always very very wrong. Why do you do it?

Comment: @Timo yes fixed